# Method not allow in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I got HTTP method not allowed in my python3 script. Help me please.

```
import urllib.request as urlRequest
import urllib.parse as urlParse

url = "http://s137934-103107-8z4.croto.hack.me/hackme.html"
values = {"field": "<img src=x onerror=window.open('https://www.google.com/');>"}

# encode values for the url
params = urlParse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")

# create the url
targetUrl = urlRequest.Request(url=url, data=params)

# open the url
x  = urlRequest.urlopen(targetUrl)


# read the response
respone = x.read()
print(respone)
```

[Error-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umIUU.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
import urllib.request as urlRequest
import urllib.parse as urlParse

url = "http://s137934-103107-8z4.croto.hack.me/hackme.html"
values = {"field": "<img src=x onerror=window.open('https://www.google.com/');>"}

# encode values for the url
params = urlParse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")

# create the url
targetUrl = urlRequest.Request(url=url, data=params)

# open the url
x  = urlRequest.urlopen(targetUrl)
with urlRequest.urlopen(url) as f:
     print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

when I try this response:HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Because:You are not allowed to view this page because your sandbox is restricted by IP.
This means you are using a different IP address from the one assigned when you started the sandbox.
Don't worry, you'll be redirected to the hackme page in a few seconds, please reset your sandbox to allow your new IP.